# MongoDB "$or" update

Tags: python, mongodb

I have some code that deletes multiple objects from Mongo using an `$or` opperator, or at least it should. This code illustrates basically what my app is doing

```
lookup = []
listofids = ['4e86fee56607f2a8a2000002','4e86fee56607f2a8a2000003','4e86feeb6607f2a8a2000006']
for id in listofids:
    lookup.append({'_id':core.ObjectId(id)})

r = self.db().photos.update({
    "$or":lookup
},{
    '$set':{'var':'value'}
})
```

That doesn't work, it doesn't update any documents. However if I change the code to do a basic find

```
lookup = []
listofids = ['4e86fee56607f2a8a2000002','4e86fee56607f2a8a2000003','4e86feeb6607f2a8a2000006']
for id in listofids:
    lookup.append({'_id':core.ObjectId(id)})

r = self.db().photos.find({
    "$or":lookup
})

for rs in r:
    self.write(str(rs)+"\n\n")
```

it outputs all the records. How do I get Mongo to update the records?

self.db() maps to a MongoDB database, photos is the collection.

This code is in Python, but I would imagine the syntax is easy enough to follow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `multi` parameter to `True` in order to update *all* documents that match your query. Otherwise, it only updates the first one (which you probably just don’t notice). See [Collection.update](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update).

(Also note: if you’re querying on multiple values of a single field, you can use the [$in operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in).)